# NSOperation - setMaxConcurrentOperationCount

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Am creating a class for network Requests say NetworkManager which is a singleton. I want this class to handle network requests.

I have two `NSOperationQueues`, one for parallel requests,where am not setting the numberofConcurrent `Operations`. For sequential queue am setting `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount` to one. I thought, the second `NSOperation` request will execute once the first request execution is over. It only runs the first `NSOperation`, which handles the network request. What should be done if i have to handle the requests sequentially. Below is the sample code:

```
NSOperation *networkOperation = [[NetworkOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request networkRequest:networkRequest];
    if(!sequentialQueue){
        sequentialQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];

        [sequentialQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
    }

    [sequentialQueue addOperation:networkOperation];
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass an [`NSOperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html) and override the `- addOperation:` method like this.

```
- (void)addOperation:(NSOperation *)operation {

    // check whether the queue has at least one operation, you can also check for nil
    if ([[self operations] count] > 0) [operation addDependency:[self.operations lastObject]];

    [super addOperation:operation];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue was that I have overridden start method of NSoperation but did not call [super start]. So, after i added that it is executing sequentially without the above logic, when i set maxcouncurrentoperationCount to 1.

Comment: I want few suggestions from you. 1)I want to maintain priority within the sequential queue also. How can i implement this.2)If a network request has to be cancelled, the function call will come to the network manager class. How can i cancel the request as there is no reference  to the operation after i add it to the NSOperationQueue. For the request to be cancelled, the parameter passed will be the NetworkRequest object which contains the URL and other request related info.

Comment: hmm... thats why I ask you to post some more code. OK, for you requirement adding dependency wont help, so do it with  -maxCouncurrentOperationCount. Use ´- (void)setQueuePriority:(NSOperationQueuePriority)priority´ to prioritize the operation. For your second question, simply keep the reference of your operations and   check the status and cancel it. Or simply search your operation by comparing NSURLRequest to NSURL. But keep in mind: canceling an added operation has no guaranty that, that will be canceled.

Comment: @Goppinath- How will the NSOperationQueue know whether an NSOperation has completed its execution, if the maxCouncurrentOperationCount is set to 1.

Comment: @user694688 - Again I am confused, you can use the property of NSOperationQueue ´operations´ there you can check the state of each and every operation like ready, executing or finished. Please refer Apple's wonderful documentation for further questions.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem sounds that you need to regulate the order of the operation where you have to use the,

```
- (void)addDependency:(NSOperation *)operation
```

method of `NSOperation` to say hey you have to operate after one specific operation. Lets take an example:

```
NSOperation *firstOperation = [NSOperation new]; // do your own init
NSOperation *secoundOperation = [NSOperation new];

[secoundOperation addDependency:firstOperation];
```

where the secoundOperation will be processed guaranteed after firstOperation. If you set only the – maxConcurrentOperationCount where you can't guaranty the order of the operation.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks. But, why setting the maxConcurrentOperationCount to 1 does not execute the next operation after the first one is completed. Is NSOperationQueue not a queue based implementation

Comment: Are you adding both operations to the queue? I could not see it. Will you please post more code?

Comment: I am conduced now... Is that you question about the sequence of the operation or about the failure of your second operation?

Comment: Yes am adding two operations now for testing. When am not setting the maxConcurrentOperationCount am able to notice two threads executing in parallel.

Comment: My issue is that second operation is not executing at all if i set the maxConcurrentOperations to one.

Comment: check whether your are canceling other operations after the execution of the first. Otherwise you have to give me more code to see.

Comment: I dont have anything great in the code. I have extended NSOperation and have a new class.Am creating two instances of the class and adding it the NSOperationQueue. Have overriden the start method to print the NSOperation instance. When i set the count to 1 , am seeing only one thread running. It does not execute the next thread after the completion of first. Please tell me will the NSOperationQueue execute the NSOperation in sequential manner if we set the maxConcurrentOperationCount to 1.

Comment: No, definitely not. If you want the sequence or order the you have to use ´- (void)addDependency:(NSOperation *)operation´ method. Which is the basic of multi-threading the order is not guaranteed.

Comment: My requirement is this. Please let me know the best way to implement. I am developing a class for handling network requests. I want to handle parallel and sequential network requests. I have two NSOperation queues- one for parallel and other one for sequential requests. Parallel requests is fine when i dont set the maxOperationCount, what should be done for sequential requests. Should i maintain the list of NSoperations in an array and add dependency as you suggest. Moreover, i have kept this class as a singleton for handling requests.

Comment: please see my second answer.